# How is it possible that SonarQube Quality Gate is passing when the project is a mess?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm kinda new to SonarQube and I just found this:

[image: Project I found on SonarQube]

Question: How? Shouldn't the Quality Gate be failing? Or do the quality gate only work for new code?
The quality rules are the default ones

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Why? It depends how the Quality Gate is configured.

Copied from SonarQube [Quality Gates documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/quality-gates/):

> Each Quality Gate condition is a combination of:
>
> - measure
> - comparison operator
> - error value
>
> For instance, a condition might be:
>
> - measure: Blocker issue
> - comparison operator: >
> - error value: 0
>
> Which can be stated as: No blocker issues.

Your Quality Gate could be configured to check only new code or even to not check the code at all.

`Sonar way` (Built-in) Quality Profile on SonarQube 7.9.2 checks only new code:

[image: Sonar way configuration]